# How to import certificate for Azure app service using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, adfs

A marketplace app in Azure is installed as an app service. For claims based authentication to work the app requires the ADFS token-signing certificate be installed on Local Machine > Trusted People store. But there is no feature like that in Azure app service where I can install a certificate to a store (I'm not trying to change SSL settings of the app).

So I went to Advanced tools > Go (Kudu tools) in Azure app service and then Debug Console > Powershell. Here I issued this command

`Import-Certificate -FilePath "D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\website.cer" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPeople" -Verbose`

This threw an error

> Import-Certificate : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid"
>   0x6 occurred while setting character attributes for the console output
>   buffer.

How do I import this certificate in Azure so that the Marketplace app can access it? Not using IaaS.

**EDIT 1**: I tried [Add-AzureCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/add-azurecertificate?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) cmdlet but it throws an error that Subscription is not selected. When I issue the [Select-AzureSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/select-azuresubscription?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) with Subscription Id specified it says subscription does not exist.

**EDIT 2**: Tried connecting using Azure Rm cmdlet as suggested in comments. But still get same error - subscription does not exist. And if it cannot find subscription I cannot add the certificate using `Import-Certificate`

Comment: Have you tried "Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId <Subscription_Id>" As you are using resource manager you should be the "AzureRm" commands.

Comment: Please see my edit 2.

Answer (score -2):

1. Login using `Connect-AzureRmAccount`
2. Select Your subscription from the list of subscriptions
3. Select your Resource Group which contains the function app service
4. Try importing now.